# How convert the specific conversational files into columns and save it in python

Tags: python, pandas, csv

This is my text file. I want to convert it into columns such as speaker and comments and save it as csv. I have a huge list.  So computing it will be helpful.

```
>bernardo11_5
Have you had quiet guard?

>francisco11_5
Not a mouse stirring.

>bernardo11_6
Well, good night.
If you do meet Horatio and Marcellus,
The rivals of my watch, bid them make haste.

>francisco11_6
I think I hear them.--Stand, ho! Who is there?

>horatio11_1
Friends to this ground.

>marcellus11_1
And liegemen to the Dane.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
import re
from pathlib import Path

import pandas as pd

input = Path('input.txt').read_text()

speaker = re.findall(">(.*)", input)
comments = re.split(">.*", input)
comments = [c.strip() for c in comments if c.strip()]

df = pd.DataFrame({'speaker': speaker, 'comments': comments})
```

This will give you full comments including newline characters.
For saving:
a) replace '\n' before calling to_csv()

```
df.comments = df.comments.str.replace('\n', '\\n')
```

b) save to a more suitable format, e.g., to_parquet()
c) split single comment into multiple rows

```
df.comments = df.comments.str.split('\n')
df.explode('comments')
```

Answer (score 1):

one way is to parse and load

read the file

```
with open("test.txt") as fp:
    data = fp.readlines()
```

remove empty lines

```
data = [x for x in data if x != "\n"]
```

separate into speaker and comments

```
speaker = []
comments = []

speaker_text = ""
for value in data:
    
    if ">" in value:
        speaker_text = value
    else:
        speaker.append(speaker_text)
        comments.append(value)
```

convert to dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "speaker": speaker,
    "comments": comments
})
```

save as csv

```
df.to_csv("result.csv", index=False)
```

output

```
            speaker                                          comments
0   >bernardo11_5\n                       Have you had quiet guard?\n
1  >francisco11_5\n                           Not a mouse stirring.\n
2   >bernardo11_6\n                               Well, good night.\n
3   >bernardo11_6\n           If you do meet Horatio and Marcellus,\n
4   >bernardo11_6\n    The rivals of my watch, bid them make haste.\n
5  >francisco11_6\n  I think I hear them.--Stand, ho! Who is there?\n
6    >horatio11_1\n                         Friends to this ground.\n
7  >marcellus11_1\n                       And liegemen to the Dane.\n
```

Comment: but when there is more than one line of a speaker then the output should be >bernardo11_6_1                Well, good night.
>bernardo11_6_2                If you do meet Horatio and Marcellus, The rivals of my watch, 
                                             bid them make haste.                                                                              i.e. the should be  separated with period or semi-colon or ? not in '\n'